# How to pass the array values from the javascript to apex controller and later store in custome object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, java, rerender

I am trying to get the values from `javascript` which is in array, to the apex controller and later save it.

When I check the debug logs, I see null value in it. Need help. Below is my code. I tried various methods available at the controller end, but luck. Below is the code for VF, JS & Apex.

VF code I have:-

```
<apex:form>
  <apex:actionFunction action="{!saveAccountIds}" name="sendAccountIds">
     <apex:param name="accountIds" value=""/>
  </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
```

JavaScript Code:-

```
_getAccountsList: function()
 {
varaccountIds = [];
if (this.mainDirectionDiv.children.length > 0 && this.mainDirectionDiv.children[0].children.length > 0)
{
    varliChildren = this.mainDirectionDiv.children[0].children;
    for (i = 0; i < liChildren.length; i++)
    {
        accountIds.push(liChildren[i].getAttribute("liAccountId"));
    }

    console.log(accountIds);
}
sendAccountIds(accountIds);
}
```

Controller end:-

```
public void saveAccountIds()
{
        List<String> Id = (List<String>)    (Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountIds'), List<String>.class);
    Id.add(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountIds'));
    System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE IS THE VALUE --> ' + Id);
}
```

When I check the debug logs, i see as

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE IS THE VALUE --> null
```

Once I confirm it in the debug logs, I can later think of pushing it in the object or wherever. Null value seems to be a major problem for me right now.

Comment: in javascript - create your array as JSON, use apex:actionFunction + apex:param assignTo a controller setter and then Json.deserialize into a list in controller in controller action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One more way use `assignTo`**

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!saveAccountIds}" name="sendAccountIds">
     <apex:param name="accountIds" value="" assignTo="{!strAccountIds}"/>
  </apex:actionFunction>
```

class

```
public String strAccountIds {get;set;}
public void saveAccountIds()
{
    System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE IS THE VALUE --> ' + strAccountIds );
}
```

Comment: Got the error in debug log :( 
`17:25:31.032 (32044428)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

Comment: @Mr.Orange just remove second debug ie.`System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE IS THE VALUE --> ' + strAccountIds .split(';'));` and check

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, still the same error. Trying out till the the Tushar's way out till then.

Comment: @Mr.Orange where you are getting error ?

Comment: in the debug logs...

Comment: @Mr.Orange try to initialize `strAccountIds = '';`   in constructor

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your current approach. But you can try a different one

```
_getAccountsList: function()
 {
varaccountIds = '';
if (this.mainDirectionDiv.children.length > 0 && this.mainDirectionDiv.children[0].children.length > 0)
{
    varliChildren = this.mainDirectionDiv.children[0].children;
    for (i = 0; i < liChildren.length; i++)
    {
        accountIds = accountIds +liChildren[i].getAttribute("liAccountId")+';';
    }

    console.log(accountIds);
}
sendAccountIds(accountIds);
}
```

now in your controller split this using (';'). You will again get the list.

```
public void saveAccountIds()
{
       string str= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountIds');
    System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE IS THE VALUE --> ' + str.split(';'));
}
```

Comment: actually my js file is in the resource bundle and not within the vf page. that's the issue. I'm sure that the values are being reaching till the js, but further not traversing till the controller. Well about spiting, I did read about and tried but not working. Getting errors in mavens.

Comment: try my method also is your actionfunction get called?

Comment: actionfunction is the only way am trying right now, as that's the only way to reach the JS file. I have also included the `<apex:includescript` for including that JS file which is in the resource bundle, but no luck as of now.